# Why is it important to get the cosine of an angle theta instead of the angle itself in two unit vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, angle

I'm a bit confused about why is it important to get the cosine of an angle theta instead of the angle itself in two unit vectors? I mean, to get the cousine theta angle we need to dot product of the two unit vectors, but why the cosine theta angle and not the angle?

A · B = cos *O*(theta)

Thank you.

Comment: Just an example: Let $A$ and $B$ be the same unit vector (i.e. $A=B$). Surely we should expect the angle between a vector and itself to be zero. But $A\cdot A = |A|^2 = 1$, so not taking the cosine would imply that the angle between $A$ and itself is $1$.